# Redux: functions passed in mapDispatchToProps "not a function"

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am in the process of setting up a simple React app with redux. I am able to access my store and pass them into components as props, but I can't seem to get the component to recognize the functions in mapDispatchToProps. I just want to call the function `searchCompany`with onClick within the child. Any advice is appreciated.

Here is the parent component:

```
class ResearchContainer extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return <CompanyFinancials test={this.handleTest} props={this.props} />
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        researchCompany: state.researchCompany
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        searchCompany: (ticker) => {
            dispatch(operations.getAndSetResearchCompany(ticker))
        },
        getResearchCompany: (ticker) => {
            dispatch(operations.getResearchCompany(ticker))
        }
    }
}
    
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ResearchContainer);
```

And here is the child. I've tried destructuring the props and accessing directly as a sanity check.

```
class CompanyFinancials extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const {
      researchCompany,
      searchCompany
    } = this.props

    let ticker = null;

    return (
      <div className="generalPage">
          <h2 className="pageHeader">{ ticker != '' ? `${ticker} Financials` : 'Research A Company' }</h2>
          <div className="companySearch-research">
            <div className="rightSideGrid-watchList-header">Search By Ticker</div>
            {/* <Button style={{backgroundColor:'red'}}onClick={() => bloombergInfo()}>Get Bloomberg Info</Button> */}

            <Formik className="ticker-input" initialValues={{ tickerInput: '' }} 
              validate={values => validateTicker(values)} validateOnChange={false} validateOnBlur={false}
              onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
                  // searchCompany(values.tickerInput.toUpperCase());
                  setSubmitting(false);
              }}
            >
              {({
                values,
                errors,
                touched,
                handleChange,
                handleBlur,
                handleSubmit,
                isSubmitting,
                /* and other goodies */
              }) => (
                <form autoComplete="off" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                  {/* <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Outlined" variant="outlined" type="ticker" value={values.tickerInput}
                  onBlur={handleBlur} onChange={event => changeTickerInput(event.target.value)}/> */}
                  <TextField className="tickerInput" size="small" label="Ticker" variant="outlined" name="tickerInput"
                    value={values.tickerInput} onChange={handleChange}/>
                  <Button className="tickerSearchBtn" type="submit" 
                    onClick={() => this.props.searchCompany(values.tickerInput.toUpperCase())}
                  >
                    Search
                  </Button>
                  <div className="form-error">{errors.tickerInput}</div>
                </form>
              )}
            </Formik>
          </div>
      </div>
      );
    }
}
```

I'm also including the logs props inside the child component.

[image: Link to Console Log Screenshot]

The error is:

```
CompanyFinancials.js:62 Uncaught TypeError: this.props.searchCompany is not a function
at onClick (CompanyFinancials.js:62)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994)
at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056)
at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4070)
at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:8243)
at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:8275)
at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:8288)
at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:8299)
at react-dom.development.js:8508
at batchedEventUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:22396)
at batchedEventUpdates (react-dom.development.js:3745)
at dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem (react-dom.development.js:8507)
at attemptToDispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:6005)
at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:5924)
at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:646)
at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11276)
at discreteUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:22413)
at discreteUpdates (react-dom.development.js:3756)
at dispatchDiscreteEvent (react-dom.development.js:5889)
```

Comment: Is the error/warning about `searchCompany` callback or about `operations.getAndSetResearchCompany` wrapped within the function? Can you include all relevant code and what the error actually is (as plain text), this may include any stacktraces also logged to the console? Also, why don't you just decorate `CompanyFinancials` directly in the `connect` HOC?

Comment: Edited to include error; it is due to the `searchCompany` callback, not the wrapped function. And my next step would be to decorate `CompanyFinancials` directly, but I really wanted to interact with the store from parent containers with `mapDispatchToProps`, as that's how I've seen it done on another project.

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

You pass the injected `researchCompany`, `searchCompany`, and `getResearchCompany` props to `CompanyFinancials` on a `props` prop.

```
class ResearchContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <CompanyFinancials test={this.handleTest} props={this.props} />
  }
}
```

So in the child they would need to be accessed from the `props.props` prop as `this.props.props.searchCompany`. `this.props.searchCompany` is undefined.

## Solution

Pass all props through to the child via the Spread syntax

```
class ResearchContainer extends React.Component {
  const { props } = this;
  render() {
    return <CompanyFinancials test={this.handleTest} {...props} />
  }
}
```

Or explicitly pass them.

```
class ResearchContainer extends React.Component {
  const { researchCompany, searchCompany, getResearchCompany } = this.props;
  render() {
    return (
      <CompanyFinancials
        test={this.handleTest}
        researchCompany={researchCompany}
        searchCompany={searchCompany}
        getResearchCompany={getResearchCompany}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Or just decorate the `CompanyFinancials` directly so the correct props are injected and you don't need to worry about proxying them correctly.

```
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CompanyFinancials);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!!! You were completely right; I should have been injecting the props with `{...this.props}` instead of explicitly with `props={this.props}`